# Need to setup a gitlab mirror of a bitbucket repo with only ONE branch exposed

Tags: gitlab, bitbucket, branch, mirror

I need to only expose one branch from my bitbucket repo to a new gitlab repo.  My students are using the gitlab.com world and I have all my teaching stuff in bitbucket repo's.  And I would like to have specific branches for specific classes.

For example:

Bitbucket has the repo APCSA
with the branches:
master
per1
per2
per3
dev

I want to have different repo's setup on gitlab under different gitlab groups.

So under one group I'd like to have them see only:

APCSA:per1 branch (and I'd love to figure out how to mirror this)

I've tried lots of combo's of mirroring but it always mirrors the entire repo, all branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a GitLab CI/CD [pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines.html) to clone, or pull, a single branch. Your pipeline can run on a different branch, in order to avoid conflicts and such.

Using the web ui,

- create a new branch called `mirror`
- in Settings, populate CI/CD variables: your upstream, the branch to mirror, and your repo address
- create a new file called `.gitlab-ci.yml` in the `mirror` branch

  - the pipeline will be trigged upon (each) commit, and you'll be able to check if it's working
- create a [scheduled pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/schedules.html) to update your repository with the desired frequency

This is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` to mirror an upstream branch:

```
job:
    script:
        - git remote show writable || git remote add writable $WRITABLE_URL
        - git checkout $UPSTREAM_BRANCH || git checkout -b $UPSTREAM_BRANCH
        - git pull $UPSTREAM_URL $UPSTREAM_BRANCH
        - git push writable $UPSTREAM_BRANCH
    only:
        - mirror
```

The variables are:

- `WRITABLE_URL` = destination, ie: 'git@gitlab.myplace.local:upstream/ansible.git'
- `UPSTREAM_URL` = origin, ie: 'https://github.com/ansible/ansible.git'
- `UPSTREAM_BRANCH` = ie: 'stable-2.8'

You will need to use the command line to install [gitlab-runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/), if you don't have one already. You will also need to create a [deploy key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/) (Settings / Repository) in order to allow `push` to work (or use [deploy token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/), but write access is not available in the free plan for deploy tokens).

Comment: I tried this and I don't know where to add the command...
Do I just create a blank repo and then run the command to create a submodule?

I'm trying to set all this up in the webui.  Is that my problem?  Should I do this all via command line?

Comment: I added some details to my initial answer.

Comment: That did it.  Thank you for taking the time to write all that down.  The documentation is really lacking ... or maybe I'm just dense and can't read it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler, with [GitLab 16.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/05/22/gitlab-16-0-released/#mirror-specific-branches-only) (May 2023):

> ### Mirror specific branches only
>
> Do you need to mirror a busy repository with many branches, but you only need a few of them? Limit the number of branches you mirror by creating a regular expression that matches only the branches you need.
>
> Previously, mirrors required you to mirror an entire repository, or all protected branches.
>
> This new flexibility can decrease the amount of data your mirrors push or pull, and keep sensitive branches out of public mirrors.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_0/mirror_specific_branches_only.png -- Mirror specific branches only]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/#mirror-specific-branches) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/1893).